# Need to allow ppt files to be selected by UIDocumentPicker

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I need to allow ppt,docx, xlsx and pdf files only to be picked up by document picker in my application. What I need to set as document types when I initialize my document picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added couple of types in the below mentioned code, please check if it solves your issue:

```
let types: [String] = [kUTTypePDF as String,kUTTypeSpreadsheet as String, kUTTypePresentation as String, "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "public.text"]
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .import)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

.

Other available types which you can try:

> "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers",
>   "com.apple.iwork.keynote.key","public.image", "com.apple.application",
>   "public.item","public.data", "public.content",
>   "public.audiovisual-content", "public.movie",
>   "public.audiovisual-content", "public.video", "public.audio",
>   "public.text", "public.data", "public.zip-archive",
>   "com.pkware.zip-archive", "public.composite-content", "public.text", " "com.microsoft.word.doc"

Please comment if you have any question.

Happy to help!

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta please mark this answer as accpeted if this solves your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this help. Just an update that I used "com.microsoft.word.doc" for word documents.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the post for com.microsoft.word.doc