# How to hide unnecessary files in UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to hide the files that do not match the document types passed to the UIDocumentPickerViewController, i.e only show those that match.

For example, if the document type is "public.movie", I want only video files and folders to be shown in the picker.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to allow ppt files to be selected by UIDocumentPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118397/need-to-allow-ppt-files-to-be-selected-by-uidocumentpicker)

Comment: @MohitKumar Thanks for your help, but that's not what I mean. What I want is that any files which are not video files will not be shown in the picker.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code:

```
let types: [String] = ["public.movie", "public.video"]
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .import)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you can add/remove any value from types as per your need:

```
let types: [String] = ["public.movie", "public.video"]
```

Please comment if you have any problem with the code.

Happy to Help!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not what I mean. What I want is that any files which are not video files will not be shown in the picker.

Comment: Do you want only video type content or other content types except for video type? I am lil confused here.

Comment: I want only video type files to appear in the picker. Any other type should disappear, not just gray out.

Comment: Can you post your code above and a screenshot of the current look?